# show next or previous Array word on onclick?

Tags: flutter, dart

Hello friends I am creating learning app I need little help here I have array list when anyone click any word it goes to next sacreen user go to next sacreen instead user come back to pervious sacreen for next word I want user click on next button or pervious button to show next word  pervious word on same sacreen.instead coming back to my previous word how it possible and remember array word must shown from right left because it an Hebrew language app here my image and code?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z0eJA.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o4fNK.jpg)

```
  import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_fonts/google_fonts.dart';

import 'Sounds.dart';
class Kamiz extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _KamizState createState() => _KamizState();
}



class _KamizState extends State<Kamiz> {
  var kamiz=['פָּרָ','חָםָ','נָבָּ','עָוָ','אָםָ','מָרָ','כָּכָּ','מָמָ','פָּפָּ','בָּרָ','קָרָ','דָּרָ','וָרָ','הָרָ','תָּרָ','בָּם','כָּלָ','כָּר','שָׁלָ','סָרָ','כָּכָּ','אָםָ','חָםָ','אָל','כָּלָ'];

  var list=['57.wav','48.wav','47.wav','46.wav','45.wav','55.wav','54.wav','53.wav','51.wav','50.wav','60.wav','61.wav','58.wav',
    '57.wav','61.wav','65.wav','64.wav','63.wav','62.wav','missing.wav','70.wav','69.wav','48.wav','67.wav','66.wav'

  ];
  var urduvowel=['پارا','خاما','نابا','عاوا','آما','مارا','کاکا','ماما','پاپا','بارا','قارا','دارا','وارا','ہارا','تارا','باما',
  'کالا','کارا','شالا','سارا','کاکا','آما','خاما','الا','کالا'];




  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(
            'Kamatz',style:GoogleFonts.davidLibre(
          fontSize: 24,

          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
        )),

      ),
        body: GridView.builder(
            itemCount: kamiz.length,
            gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(crossAxisCount: 5,


            ),
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context,int index){
              return Padding(
                padding:EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                child: GestureDetector(
                  onTap: () {
                    Navigator.push (
                      context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Sounds(kamiz[index],list[index],urduvowel[index])),
                    );

                  },
                  child: Container(
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: Colors.black12,
                        border: Border.all(color: Colors.blueAccent)
                    ),

                    child: Center(
                      child: Directionality(
                        textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
                        child: Column(
                          children: [
                            Text(kamiz[index],style:GoogleFonts.davidLibre(
                              fontSize: 16,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            )),

                            Text(urduvowel[index],style:GoogleFonts.davidLibre(
                              fontSize: 16,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            )),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              )   ;
            }
        )
    );
  }
}

import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_fonts/google_fonts.dart';
import 'package:webview_flutter/webview_flutter.dart';
import 'package:audioplayers/audioplayers.dart';
import 'package:flutter_cache_manager_firebase/flutter_cache_manager_firebase.dart';

class Sounds extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SoundsState createState() => _SoundsState();

  String word;
  var sounds;
  var urdu;



  Sounds(this.word,this.sounds,this.urdu);
}

class _SoundsState extends State<Sounds> {
  final Completer<WebViewController> _controller = Completer<WebViewController>();
  var audio;
  AudioPlayer audioPlayer = AudioPlayer();
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
 audio='''
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<audio id="englishAudio">
  <source src="https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/hebrewapp-453d2.appspot.com/o/practicesounds%2F${widget.sounds}?alt=media&token=603fc7fc-6794-424d-84c6-3627d0d81d68" type="audio/mpeg">
  Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>



<button onclick="UrduAudio()" type="button">Listen Word</button>
<button onclick="pauseAudio()" type="button">Pause Audio</button>  
<script>

var x = document.getElementById("englishAudio"); 
var y = document.getElementById("urduAudio"); 

function UrduAudio() { 
  x.play(); 
} 

function englishAudio() {  
  y.play();
} 

function pauseAudio() { 
  x.pause(); 
  y.pause();
} 
</script>

</body>
</html>
    
    ''';
  }







  @override

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {



    @override

String audioplay='''
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<audio id="englishAudio">
  <source src="https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/hebrewapp-453d2.appspot.com/o/practicesounds%2F${widget.sounds}?alt=media&token=603fc7fc-6794-424d-84c6-3627d0d81d68" type="audio/mpeg">
  Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>



<button onclick="UrduAudio()" type="button">Listen Word</button>
<button onclick="pauseAudio()" type="button">Pause Audio</button>  
<script>

var x = document.getElementById("englishAudio"); 
var y = document.getElementById("urduAudio"); 

function UrduAudio() { 
  x.play(); 
} 

function englishAudio() {  
  y.play();
} 

function pauseAudio() { 
  x.pause(); 
  y.pause();
} 
</script>

</body>
</html>
    
    ''';
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(
            'Kamatz',style:GoogleFonts.davidLibre(
          fontSize: 24,

          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
        )),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Container(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
          Text(
              widget.urdu+'/'+widget.word,style:GoogleFonts.davidLibre(
            fontSize: 70,


          )),
              SizedBox(height: 30,),

              Center(
                child: Padding(
                  padding:EdgeInsets.only(left: 90),
                  child: Container(
                      constraints: BoxConstraints(maxHeight: 100,),

                      child: WebView(
                        initialUrl:Uri.dataFromString(audio, mimeType: 'text/html').toString(),
                        javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
                        onWebViewCreated: (WebViewController webViewController) {
                          _controller.complete(webViewController);

                        }, //
                      )
                  ),
                ),
              ),

             Padding(
               padding:EdgeInsets.only(left: 20),
               child: Row(
                 mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                 children: [
                   Text('PERV'),
                   Icon(
                     Icons.arrow_left,

                     size: 70.0,
                   ),

                   Icon(

                     Icons.arrow_right,
                     size: 70.0,
                   ),
                   Text('Next'),
                 ],
               ),
             )
            ],
         
         
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `-` for previous and `+` for next

```
var kamiz=['פָּרָ','חָםָ','נָבָּ','עָוָ','אָםָ','מָרָ','כָּכָּ','מָמָ','פָּפָּ','בָּרָ','קָרָ','דָּרָ','וָרָ','הָרָ','תָּרָ','בָּם','כָּלָ','כָּר','שָׁלָ','סָרָ','כָּכָּ','אָםָ','חָםָ','אָל','כָּלָ'];
int index = 0;
int prev = kamiz[index-1];
int next = kamiz[index+1];
```

Make sure to check bounds.